# Why can't I ping an interface on another VLAN?

Tags: networking, router, pfsense, tomato

I have Netgear R7000 set up with FreshTomato, configured to act as a wireless AP. It has two bridges, feeding two virtual access points (SSIDs). The IP of one bridge is 192.168.3.2, and the other is 192.168.4.2. The access point is connected to a pfSense router, which handles routing between the 192.168.3.0/24 and 192.168.4.0/24 networks. As far as I can tell, everything is working fine, with one exception. If I try to access the Tomato webui from a device on the 192.168.4.0/24 using the ip 192.168.3.2 (or vice versa), I get nothing.

Shouldn't accessing 192.168.3.2 from 192.168.4.0/24 go to the gateway (pfSense 192.168.4.1) and then get routed to 192.168.3.2 correctly from there?

Comment: It is normal for two VLANs to be separate.  You must provide a routing table in order for one VLAN to talk to another VLAN.  It doesn't sound like your pfSense configuration is correct.

Comment: @Ramhound Don't think that's the case. All other clients on 192.168.4.0/24 can reach all other clients on 192.168.3.0/24. The Tomato bridge interfaces and by extension the webui is the only exception.

Comment: On which IP is your webui listening? Can you ping this IP from your pfSense router? Is HTTP enabled toward the “inside” on your pfSense router?

Comment: @dan From 192.168.3.0/24 webui is listening on 192.168.3.2. On 192.168.4.0/24 webui is listening on 192.168.4.2. pfSense can ping both IPs.